# Declare and bound the Queue using @queuebinding with @rabbitlistener not working?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to make a spring-amqp sample using annotation and rabbitlistener, but it didn't work out when using queuebinding to declare the queue automatically. 
any advise about this?? thx a lot.

here is the consumer code:

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = "queue1", durable = "true") , 
            exchange = @Exchange(value = "test"), 
            key = "hello1") )
    public void handleHello1(String text) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + text);
    }

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = "queue2", durable = "true") , 
            exchange = @Exchange(value = "test") , 
            key = "hello2") )
    public void handleHello2(String text) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + text);
    }
}
```

The config code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit 
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        System.out.println("create rabbitListenerContainerFactory");
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        AmqpAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        System.out.println("create amqpAdmin");
        return admin;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ScheduledProducer scheduledProducer() {
        return new ScheduledProducer();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor postProcessor() {
        return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }


    static class ScheduledProducer {
        @Autowired
        private volatile RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
        private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
        public void sendMessage() {
            String str = "hello" +(counter.get() % 2);
            System.out.println("routingkey:" + str);
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("test", str, "Hello World " + counter.incrementAndGet());
        }
    }
}
```

the Produce code:

```
public class Producer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Consumer` to your `Config` class...

```
@Bean
public Consumer consumer() {
    return new Consumer();
}
```

(or enable component scan on `Config`).

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="foo")
```

The routing keys in the bindings are wrong too - you are sending to `hello0` and `hello1`.